# How to configure chrome to NOT use windows certificate store

Tags: google-chrome, security, tls

By default it appears firefox does not trust the windows certificate store (which is good).

Is it possible to configure chrome to **not** trust the windows certificate store?

I can't use Firefox because there are some plugins I use that are only available in Chrome. There are some CA certificates on my work computer that I don't trust and I want to know about any SSL MITM attempt. I doubt this would happen, it's more likely the private key for the CA cert might be leaked.

I found this link on managing certificates
https://certsimple.com/blog/control-the-ssl-cas-your-browser-trusts

https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy
Google can manually revoke certificates for chrome, however is it possible for users to do the same?

Comment: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy

google keeps a list of CA certs they dont trust no matter what you have in your store. Is it possible for users to manually revoke certificates they dont trust?

Comment: is there any way to do this? any updates?